# Openshift MySQL Cartridge not restarting

Tags: python, mysql, openshift

I just updated my Openshift Python application and since, the MySQL cartridge won't start:

```
Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
MySQL server failed to start:
140331 15:07:07 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/openshift/531b9311500446a962000021/mysql//log/mysql_error.log'.
140331 15:07:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/531b9311500446a962000021/mysql/data/
140331 15:07:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/531b9311500446a962000021/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended
140331 15:07:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/531b9311500446a962000021/mysql/data/
140331 15:07:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140331 15:07:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140331 15:07:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140331 15:07:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140331 15:07:08 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140331 15:07:08  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 5 failed.
140331 15:07:10  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
140331 15:07:10 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
140331 15:07:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140331 15:07:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140331 15:07:10 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140331 15:07:10 [ERROR] Aborting

140331 15:07:10 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140331 15:07:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/531b9311500446a962000021/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/531b9311500446a962000021/mysql
```

I'm kinda stuck. I checked my quota, everything's fine, it's just a small application for test purpose. What can I do apart from deleting the gear and creating a new one?

Is this a bug on Openshift side?

Comment: did you try disabling AIO, as the error suggested?

Comment: I've read that it will do more harm than anything. I've restarted the MySQL cartidge dozens of time the past months and I had no errors..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a bug (http://elenst.ru/mariadb/aio-max-nr-in-general-and-innodb-error-io_setup-failed-with-eagain-in-particular/) (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61575) we are looking into work arounds